# SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() Not Working

Tags: java, android, arrays, real-time, chronometer

I was use chronometer to make a Stopwatch with this code

```
public class ChronoExample extends Activity {
 Chronometer mChronometer;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
     layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

     mChronometer = new Chronometer(this);

     // Set the initial value
     mChronometer.setText("00:00:00.000");
     layout.addView(mChronometer);

     Button startButton = new Button(this);
     startButton.setText("Start");
     startButton.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);
     layout.addView(startButton);

     Button stopButton = new Button(this);
     stopButton.setText("Stop");
     stopButton.setOnClickListener(mStopListener);
     layout.addView(stopButton);

     Button resetButton = new Button(this);
     resetButton.setText("Reset");
     resetButton.setOnClickListener(mResetListener);
     layout.addView(resetButton);        

     setContentView(layout);
 }

 private void showElapsedTime() {
     long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mChronometer.getBase();            
     Toast.makeText(ChronoExample.this, "Elapsed milliseconds: " + elapsedMillis, 
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }

 View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
        int stoppedMilliseconds = 0;

         String chronoText = mChronometer.getText().toString();
         String array[] = chronoText.split(":");
         if (array.length == 2) {
           stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 1000
               + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 1000;
         } else if (array.length == 3) {
           stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 1000
               + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 1000;
         } else if (array.length == 4) {
               stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000 
               + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 60 * 1000
               + Integer.parseInt(array[2]) * 1000;
         } else if (array.length == 5) {
               stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 
               + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 60 * 60 * 1000
               + Integer.parseInt(array[2]) * 60 * 1000
               + Integer.parseInt(array[3]) * 1000;
             }

         mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() - stoppedMilliseconds);
         mChronometer.start();
     }
 };

 View.OnClickListener mStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         mChronometer.stop();
         showElapsedTime();
     }
 };

 View.OnClickListener mResetListener = new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
         showElapsedTime();
     }
 };
```

I'm not sure with my code here to declare the format to "HH:MM:SS.SSS" in this line, maybe someone can help me fix this

```
        int stoppedMilliseconds = 0;

         String chronoText = mChronometer.getText().toString();
         String array[] = chronoText.split(":");
         if (array.length == 2) {
           stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 1000
               + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 1000;
         } else if (array.length == 3) {
           stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 1000
               + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 1000;
         } else if (array.length == 4) {
               stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000 
               + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 60 * 1000
               + Integer.parseInt(array[2]) * 1000;
         } else if (array.length == 5) {
               stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 
               + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 60 * 60 * 1000
               + Integer.parseInt(array[2]) * 60 * 1000
               + Integer.parseInt(array[3]) * 1000;
             }

         mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() - stoppedMilliseconds);
         mChronometer.start();
```

I purpose to make it Show "hh:mm:ss.SSS" but in emulator it seems bug like this

[image]

Chronometer not count time but count something like + ( ) '

Anyone can help me to fix this? thanks-